# Enum drives with name in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I'm actually trying to enum my laptop drives and return this to client. How can I enum drives with their name?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require('child_process').exec("wmic logicaldisk get name", console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect! I use 'wmic logicaldisk get name, volumename'